# Delete a failed bootcamp partition MacBook Pro

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

I just tried to install windows with Boot Camp on my Macbook Pro running macOS Sierra. Just when Boot Camp wanted to split my Mac's hard drive into partitions, I stopped it, leaving some useless space taken up on my hard drive.

Now, I don't know how to delete that bootcamp space (about 40 GB); the bootcamp partition does not even appear in Disk Utility.

How can I delete this partition and free up its storage space?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps or not, just add a comment with `@owlswipe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recall a few years back I had difficulty removing a boot camp partition with the boot camp utility.  I wound up using disk utility to remove the boot camp partition and resize my Macintosh hard drive back to its initial state.

[image]

Select the book camp partition in the pie chart and then just hit the minus button beneath

[image]

After that I just wound up using the Boot Camp utility again to start the whole process over of creating a new partition for Boot Camp

Comment: @EdgarKAMDEM I just noticed you mentioned your Bootcamp partition does not appear in disk utility.  Before going any further, it may be a good idea to reboot your system and as soon as you hear the startup chime, immediately press and hold the Command + R keys.  This will bring you to the option of running disk utility while not being logged into your system.  Go ahead and try running that and then reboot normally and see what happens in your boot camp utility and or disk utility again

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Boot Camp Assistant to delete your Boot Camp partition.

> 1. Launch the **Boot Camp Assistant** by going to [**Finder** ->] **Applications** -> **Utilities** -> **Boot Camp Assistant** [or searching Spotlight for **Boot Camp Assistant**].
> 2. Click **Continue** on the initial Boot Camp Assistant Introduction window.
> 3. Select **Create or remove a Windows partition** and then click **Continue**.
> 4. Click the **Restore** button to remove the Windows partition and restore the disk to a single partition [macOS] volume.
> 5. You’ll be prompted to enter your password – do so and then click **OK**.
>
> The Boot Camp Assistant will start partitioning and then you’ll be back to a single [macOS] volume. That’s it – Windows is gone.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3955314.

Comment: When I click on `Continue`, I get this message : `The disk must have at least 50 GB of free space` (which is normal, because, the last BootCamp operation took up 40GB space). I don't have unfortunately  `Create or remove a Windows partition` option :(

Comment: @EdgarKAMDEM Hmm. Does your disk have at least 50 GB of free space? If not, maybe delete some files and try again?

Comment: The fact is that, my disk did have 80 GB of free space, and  when I wanted to install windows and I stopped the BootCamp partitionning operation (which would took 40 GB of my space), my free disk space is become 40 GB. In fact I have 40GB of useless space coming from the last (and failed) BootCamp operation, and I don't know how to get rid of that !

Comment: @EdgarKAMDEM I guess you might have to delete 10 GB of stuff

Answer (score -1):

The only good way to delete a bootcamp partition is with BootcampAssistant. Period.